# Why is it mandatory to use namespace std in new IDEs whereas the programs written in Turbo C++/Borland C++ don't require namespace std?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, turbo-c++

Why is it mandatory to use `namespace std` in new compilers whereas the programs written in Turbo C++/Borland C++ don't require namespace std ?

This works in old compilers

```cpp
#include <iostream.h>

int main () {
   cout << "Hello Programmers";

   return 0;
}
```

but we have to write the below given program in new compilers instead of the above one, as the above programs don't work in new compilers.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
   cout << "Hello Programmers";

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Turbo C++ is ancient history. It cannot be used to write modern C++ code. You need to switch to more current C++ compiler.

Comment: Consider GCC or clang on linux/bsd/macOS, MinGW on windows (or, if you insist on, MSVC).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because turbo-c++ was released even before any c++ standard was released, and they didn't introduce a `std` namespace.

It was never updated since then.

Also it isn't mandatory to use the `using namespace std;` statement, but [rather discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

The code should be:

```
#include <iostream>

int main () {
   std::cout << "Hello Programmers";
}
```

or

```
#include <iostream>
int main () {
   using std::cout;    
   cout << "Hello Programmers";
}
```

---

Also IMO questions about turbo-c++ are quite futile this time. It's outdated and not remotely has to do anything with modern c++.
If your professors / teachers force you to use it<sup>1</sup>, tell them that they're doing it wrong and don't teach c++ in any way.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>I know it's common at indian schools, but that's simply bad practice, and doesn't have a sound reasoning.

May be they want you to teach some things *from scratch*, because turbo-c++ doesn't support containers like `std::vector` or such.

But I still believe that's the wrong approach, because manual memory management is advanced stuff, and shouldn't be used to confuse beginners.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I might be splitting hairs, but it is **never** mandatory to use `using namespace std;`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) for why it is considered bad pratice.

Your first version may "work" in some ancient non-standard conformant compilers.

What you should do is write

```
#include <iostream>    
int main () {
   std::cout << "Hello Programmers";    
   return 0;
}
```

If you are lazy you could use

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

int main () {
   cout << "Hello Programmers";
   return 0; 
}
```

And the version with `using namespace std;` is also technically correct, but it will lead to all sorts of nasty problems in bigger projects.

Comment: *'no need to return 0; from main'* – some consider it bad practice not to do so, though...

Comment: @Aconcagua I'd disagree, but thanks for pointing it out, i'll add it back in, because its a different topic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not an IDE question, but a C++ compiler (C++ language implementation) question.

The first TurboC/BorlandC was shipped decades ago, when there were no namespaces intruduced in C++.